# MacOS run java in terminal, got Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I installed JDK in my Mac, I tried to run `java` in terminal, but got this error:

`~ % java`

`Error occurred during initialization of VM`

`Unable to load native library:`

I got `/usr/bin/java` when I run `which java`. I tried to add environment variable into `.bash_profile` and got `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1/Contents/Home` when I run `echo $JAVA_HOME`. However I can run java code in IntelliJ, I think that's because IntelliJ is using some internal JDK. I'm trying to use Apache Kafka, also got `Error occurred during initialization of VM`. Anyone know what may cause this happens?

BTW, I have 6 different versions in my JavaVirtualMachines file...Not sure if that's related.

Comment: Did you `source` your `.bash_profile` after adding the JAVA_HOME? `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @WistonCoronell Yes, I `source` after adding the JAVA_HOME, I can got `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1/Contents/Home` when run echo $JAVA_HOME

Comment: Solved by myself. `export JAVA_HOME=\`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_281\` `

Comment: Cause my macOS version is Catalina, the shell is zsh now, not bash anymore. So I add `export JAVA_HOME=\`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_281\` ` into `.zshenv` file.